# Scatter plot in Process Algorithm

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I am trying to plot a scatter plot in the Process Algorithm on a data frame to show the relation between custom data and used under the K-means algorithm. But every time I try to run it. QGIS gets hung.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for cluster in clusters:
        row_ix = where(yhat == cluster)
        plt.scatter(X[row_ix, 0], X[row_ix, 1])
        plt.title('KMEANS')
        plt.legend(clusters)
        plt.show()
```

How do I go around this problem? I was able to do it in Python script but unable to do so in Python Processing Toolbox script.